# MySql doesn't use index with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

I have a table with this structure (with 50k fields):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imageid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `uid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `content` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `adate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ids` (`imageid`,`adate`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=52236 ;
```

I want to select data by imageid and sort it with adate so I added (`imageid`,`adate`) key.

but the explain result of this query says MuSQL still use table scan. Why?!

```
EXPLAIN SELECT   comments.*
FROM comments
WHERE comments.imageid=50
ORDER BY
comments.adate DESC LIMIT 10
```

result:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  comments    ref     ids     ids     4   const   203     Using where
```

and with this index:

```
KEY `ids` (`imageid`,`adate`,`id`) USING BTREE
```

the result for this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT   comments.id
FROM comments
WHERE comments.imageid=50
ORDER BY
comments.adate DESC LIMIT 10
```

IS:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  comments    ref     ids     ids     4   const   203     Using where; Using index
```

Comment: Do you have a index on imageid?

Comment: yes as you can see I have added a key KEY `ids` (`imageid`,`adate`) USING BTREE

Comment: Does it make any difference if you are selecting only the comments.id in the first example?

From my experience i can say: The easiest way to check this is via the speed. Triple your 50k entries and search for something measuring the speed with and without index on the specific fields.

Answer (score 1):

You are **not** reading the results from explain correctly.

`using index` means that the query is index-covered - the data is read only from the index, and the actual row is not used. This is not because the index is different, but because in the second query you are selecring only the id.

If MySQL does not use index for resolving the `ORDER BY` there would be `using filesort` in the explain. In both queries, `ids` key is used and MySQL **does not** perofrm a table scan

Comment: what about the "Using where"? It is displayed in both queries...!

Comment: Most likely becuase adate allow null values

Answer (score 0):

For InnoDB create a key like this (imageid,adate,id); order of column in index is important.

Then try this -

```
EXPLAIN SELECT   comments.id
FROM comments
WHERE comments.imageid=50
ORDER BY
comments.adate DESC LIMIT 10
```

Let me know what is the output.

Thanks for the output.
Adding following section below.

If you require more than id then try something like this

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT c1.* from comments as c1
JOIN
(
   SELECT comments.id
   FROM comments
   WHERE comments.imageid=50
   ORDER BY
   comments.adate DESC LIMIT 10
) as c2 ON (c1.id=c2.id)
```

But this time do not rely on Explain. Explain will show one row with index anyway still. Rather check execution time in phpmyadmin or in mysql query browser.

Comment: Thanks, I added the result to the original question

Answer (score 0):

[Straight out of the manual:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY, although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the WHERE clause. These cases include the following: ––– You use ORDER BY on nonconsecutive parts of a key:
>   SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE key2=constant ORDER BY key_part2;

Maybe this applies to your query since you have a composite `KEY ids (imageid,adate)` and you don't use `imageid` in your `ORDER BY`. You could try and add a key for `adate` only and see if that helps.